# Ajax blob return file not downloading.And not responsed.Just wait

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Please search working and not working tags in code.Working code downloading excel file successly.But not working code not downloading.I couldn't find the reason.I'm sharing console log bottom.

Details : I'm clicking button and send parameters.Button codes :

```
<input type="submit" value ="Rapor Önizle"  style="margin-top: 27px;" id="saatlikRaporOnizle"  disabled onclick="SaatlikRaporExceleAktar('Onizle')" name="saatlikRaporOnizle"  />
<input type="submit" value ="Excele Aktar"  style="margin-top: 27px;margin-left: 30px;" id="saatlikExceleAktar"  disabled onclick="SaatlikRaporExceleAktar('Excel')" name="saatlikExceleAktar"  />
```

I am sending 'Onizle' or 'Excel' parameter.Then Checking combobox :

```
<select id="saat_10dk_periyot" id="saat_10dk_periyot" class="form-control" style="width: 290px">
    <option value="saatlikPer">1 Saatlik</option>
    <option value="10dkPer">10 Dakikalık</option>
</select>
```

saatlikPer is working.But 10dkPer not working!I have added the necessary places as comment lines.Please review.

```
function SaatlikRaporExcelIslemleri(yontem)
{

    var secilen_order=$("#order2" ).val();
    var secilen_band=$("#bandno2" ).val();
    var saat_10dk_periyot=$("#saat_10dk_periyot" ).val();
    var filename = "";
    var disposition="";
    var a = "";
    var url = "";
    var filenameRegex ="";
    var matches = "";
    
    if (saat_10dk_periyot=="saatlikPer") {
        if(yontem=="Onizle") {
            Preloader_Baslat();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"./Pages/Operasyon_Islemler/Operasyon_Islemleri.php",
                data:{ saatlik_tarih:saatlik_tarih,
                checkedSaatlikAlanlar:checkedSaatlikAlanlar,
                secilen_band:secilen_band,
                secilen_order:secilen_order,
                raporCekmeYontem:yontem,
                paramSaatlik_Operasyon_Raporu_Islem:"Saatlik_Detayli_Operasyon_Raporu_Getir"
                },
            })
            .done(function(gelen_cevap){
                document.write(gelen_cevap);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){
                alert("Bir hata oluştu:"+textStatus);
            });
        } else if(yontem=="Excel") {
            Preloader_Baslat();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                xhrFields: {responseType: 'blob'},
                url:"./Pages/Operasyon_Islemler/Operasyon_Islemleri.php",
                data:{ saatlik_tarih:saatlik_tarih,
                        checkedSaatlikAlanlar:checkedSaatlikAlanlar,
                        secilen_band:secilen_band,
                        secilen_order:secilen_order,
                        raporCekmeYontem:yontem,
                        paramSaatlik_Operasyon_Raporu_Islem:"Saatlik_Detayli_Operasyon_Raporu_Getir"
                },
            })
            .done(function(gelen_cevap,status, xhr){
                //Working excel download
                disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }
        a = document.createElement('a');
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(gelen_cevap);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.append(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        Preloader_Bitir();
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){
      alert("Bir hata oluştu:"+textStatus);
    });  
    }
   
  }
  if(saat_10dk_periyot=="10dkPer")
  {
    
    if(yontem=="Onizle")
    {
          Preloader_Baslat();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"./Pages/Operasyon_Islemler/Operasyon_Islemleri.php",
      data:{ saatlik_tarih:saatlik_tarih,checkedOnDklikAlanlar:checkedOnDklikAlanlar,secilen_band:secilen_band,secilen_order:secilen_order,raporCekmeYontem:yontem,paramSaatlik_Operasyon_Raporu_Islem:"10Dklik_Detayli_Operasyon_Raporu_Getir"},
    })
    .done(function(gelen_cevap){
      document.write(gelen_cevap);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){
      alert("Bir hata oluştu:"+textStatus);
    });
    }
  }
    else if(yontem=="Excel")
    {
      Preloader_Baslat();
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
            xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
      url:"./Pages/Operasyon_Islemler/Operasyon_Islemleri.php",
      data:{ saatlik_tarih:saatlik_tarih,checkedOnDklikAlanlar:checkedOnDklikAlanlar,secilen_band:secilen_band,secilen_order:secilen_order,raporCekmeYontem:yontem,paramSaatlik_Operasyon_Raporu_Islem:"10Dklik_Detayli_Operasyon_Raporu_Getir"},
    })
    .done(function(gelen_cevap,status, xhr){
           //Not working excel download
         disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'); 
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
             filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
             matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
            if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
        }
            a = document.createElement('a');
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(gelen_cevap);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.append(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      Preloader_Bitir();
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus){
      alert("Bir hata oluştu:"+textStatus);
    });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Dreamviewer not auto ident js code.I'm sorry

Comment: Change TAB to 4 spaces and then do your own indentation as you write code. Not everything comes for free

Answer (score 0):

İt's fixed.I was sended wrong parameters...